# Modern Feature Selection Review/Resources

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-extraction

I found this review paper by Guyon and Elisseeff in a 2003 JMLR publication but, although not outdated, it is quite old. Is there a more recent review or resource on the topic of feature selection?

[JMLR Review 2003](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into it quite recently and found these papers:

- [Saeys et al. (2007)](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/23/19/2507/185254/A-review-of-feature-selection-techniques-in)  (also already a bit dated, but a good overview, and I think the 'key' paper in this area).
- [Dougherty et al. (2009)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2766788/pdf/CG-10-365.pdf)  (interesting paper discussing various difficulties such as classifier dependence, label distribution and sample size).
- [Bolòn-Canedo et al. (2014)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025514006021) .
- [Dessì & Pes (2015)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417415000925).

However, I do agree with you that there is a need for an updated review regarding this topic.

Comment: Thanks! The bioinformatics domain is exactly why I asked this question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I found a 2016 fairly comprehensive review-like paper with an associated python package built on top of scikit-learn. [Feature Selection: A Data Perspective. Li et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.07996v4.pdf)